# How do you append unknown tuples in one list that have a specific value inside them to another list?

Tags: python

I am sorry if the heading had sounded complicated. Let me show you the code:

```
a = fooList[0][0] #the 1st value of the tuple
b = fooList[0][1] #the 2nd value of the tuple
for i in range(len(fooList)):
    num = travelist.count(b)
    if num >= 1:
        templist = []
        templist.append()
```

I am trying to append all the tuples that have *b* inside them. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: All of the tuples have 'b' inside them because b is the second value of the tuple.. Could you provide some examples and counter-examples of the tuple data you want to match/not match?

Comment: What is fooList?